# How can I get symbols in a core dump if I only have a shared library?

Tags: gdb, coredump, postmortem-debugging

We ship a shared library that is used by customers to integrate in their product.

We got a core dump from a customer, by looking at `info proc mappings` I can see the modules loaded and in `thread apply all bt` I can see there are entries in the stack trace that are inside the range where our library is loaded. So it might be possible that our lib caused the crash. But we don't have access to the executable the customer used.

Is there a way to get symbols in this core dump if we only have the shared library we shipped, but not the main executable?

I tried to load the core and the library using the file command and vice versa, but stack traces don't show any symbols.

Most examples on the internet seems to imply you have access to the executable itself to be able to get meaningful symbols.
Can I get symbols for just the shared library if I load it into GDB?

Other details: the production system uses a different (much older) GCC than the one installed on my PC. And we have the unstripped version of the library available, we ship the stripped lib.

Comment: You can try using `add-symbol-file` with the unstripped library and the information from the mappings.  The version of GCC should not matter as long as the library you're looking at is the unstripped version of the one actually shipped.  Whether or not you can get a backtrace with just this setup may depend on how they compiled their code.